# WWW::Mechanize: How to get the value of a redirected URL's query parameter

Tags: perl, mechanize

On Mechanize, one can create a user agent that will simulate a web browser

```
$agent = WWW::Mechanize->new();
```

To access to a new webpage with the user agent I do the following:

```
$agent->get("http://some_url.com");
```

If I type this same URL in my browser it redirects to something like this:

```
http://some_url.com?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

How can I retrieve the value of those query parameters?

Comment: It would usually follow the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` method of [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) returns [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) object. On which you can run `redirects` method to get the complete redirection chain. For example I ran below code for [google.com](http://google.com).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $object = $agent->get('http://www.google.com/');

print Dumper $object->redirects;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_msg' => 'Found',
                 '_request' => bless( {
                                        '_headers' => bless( {
                                                               'accept-encoding' => 'gzip',
                                                               'user-agent' => 'WWW-Mechanize/1.82'
                                                             }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                                        '_uri_canonical' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://www.google.com/')}, 'URI::http' ),
                                        '_uri' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri_canonical'},
                                        '_content' => '',
                                        '_method' => 'GET'
                                      }, 'HTTP::Request' ),
                 '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                 '_rc' => '302',
                 '_headers' => bless( {
                                        'title' => '302 Moved',
                                        'content-length' => '261',
                                        'location' => 'http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=3KoEWP78GYPj8weZlLXoDA',
                                        'date' => 'Mon, 17 Oct 2016 10:41:32 GMT',
                                        'accept-ranges' => 'none',
                                        'cache-control' => 'private',
                                        'client-date' => 'Mon, 17 Oct 2016 10:41:32 GMT',
                                        'connection' => 'close',
                                        'client-response-num' => 1,
                                        'content-type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
                                        '::std_case' => {
                                                          'title' => 'Title',
                                                          'set-cookie2' => 'Set-Cookie2',
                                                          'client-peer' => 'Client-Peer',
                                                          'client-date' => 'Client-Date',
                                                          'set-cookie' => 'Set-Cookie',
                                                          'base' => 'Base',

                                                          'content-base' => 'Content-Base',
                                                          'client-response-num' => 'Client-Response-Num'
                                                        }
                                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_content' => '<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=3KoEWP78GYPj8weZlLXoDA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>   '

               }, 'HTTP::Response' );
```

As you can see the final location can be found in `location` header.

Answer (score 1):

Your [WWW::Mechanize][mech] automatically follows redirects. So when you call your `get`, it will be in a state where it already got the page with the parameters.

Since those are URL params, we can look at the URL that your Mech got. There's [a `uri` method](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-uri) that returns a [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) object, which has [a `query_form` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#uri-query_form).

But first, to test this I used [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2) to create a simple web server. It listens on port 3000 and redirects requests to `/` to `/foo?p1=bar&p2=baz`.

```
$ perl -MDancer2 -e 'get "/" => sub { redirect "/foo?p1=bar&p2=baz" }; get "/foo" => sub { "hi" }; dance;'
>> Dancer2 v0.166001 server 10889 listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Now we can code against that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://localhost:3000');

my %params = $mech->uri->query_form;
print Dumper \%params;
```

The `query_form` returns key/value pairs when called in list context. We can assign those to a hash to get a convenient way of accessing them.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'p1' => 'bar',
          'p2' => 'baz'
        };
```

If you know that a parameter appears more than once, you should use an array instead.

Comment: You mean empty @adrTuIPKJ44? There is no _void_ in Perl. First try, then accept. ;)

Comment: I just tried on http://google.fr which redirect to https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=HrQEWLJDI_SDD, and still nothing...

Comment: Yes I meant empty

Comment: @adrTuIPKJ44 google.fr doesn't redirect for me when I curl it. I think Google has a lot of stuff in place to ignore bots, because screen-scraping is against ther ToS. Try it with something else than Google.

Comment: @adr I use Data::Printer to inspect the `$mech` object. I can clearly see that the google.fr request does not get forwarded.